# $configdata and parameters

Tags: powershell, dsc

Is there any option to pass values to `$configdata` block (use for `-ConfigurationData`) as a parameter/variable?

Something like:

```
Configuration Config1
{
...
...
...
}

$configdata = @{
    AllNodes = @(
    @{
        NodeName = servername
        CertificateFile = "$path\CertFile.cer"
        Thumbprint = $CertThumb
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The Configuration Data *is* the way to pass values to the Configuration.

On the other hand, the configuration data itself is nothing more, but a Hash Table. You can edit it in any way you like.

Consider the following example.

You are in Push mode and have the following configuration:

```
Configuration MyFileCreator
{

    Import-DscResource –ModuleName 'PSDesiredStateConfiguration'

   Node localhost
   {

        File sampleFile
        {
            Ensure          = $ConfigurationData.fileEnsure
            Type            = 'File'
            DestinationPath = 'c:\temp\file.txt'
            Force           = $true
        }

        # Configure LCM
        LocalConfigurationManager
        {
            ConfigurationMode  = 'ApplyAndAutoCorrect'
            RefreshMode        = 'PUSH'
            RebootNodeIfNeeded = $False
        }

    }
}
```

You see that I have used $ConfigurationData.fileEnsure. This variable refers to a value I set in the ConfigurationData.

My ConfigurationData could look like this:

```
$myConfigurationData = @{
    AllNodes = @()
    fileEnsure      = 'absent'
}
```

If I want to apply my configuration with the configuration data, I can run the following commands:

```
MyFileCreator -ConfigurationData  $myConfigurationData
Start-DscConfiguration -ComputerName localhost .\MyFileCreator
```

If I want to change the configuration data, I can simply modify the Hash Table and apply my configuration again:

```
$myConfigurationData.fileEnsure = 'present'
MyFileCreator -ConfigurationData  $myConfigurationData
Start-DscConfiguration -ComputerName localhost .\MyFileCreator -Force
```

---

You can read more about the idea behind Configuration and Environment Data in the [official MSDN Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/dsc/configdata).